# Elasticsearch: Fields necessary for map visualization on Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, geoip

I want to make use of the `geoip` logstash plugin to get geolocation info about some IP addresses seen in my logs;

I also want to be able to visualize such info on `kibana`;

I am going through a short [overview](https://www.elastic.co/blog/geoip-in-the-elastic-stack) of the process;

What the tutorial does not mention, is what are the `geoip.*` fields necessary for producing the map visualizations;

I want to keep only the strictly necessary fields and discard the rest;

Will keeping **only** `geoip.longtitute` and `geoip.latitude` do the job?

**edit**: At this point in time I am just using

```
{ geoip { source => "my_incoming_ip" } }
```

in my logstash filter;

Comment: You simply need to have a `geo_point` field declared in your ES mapping. Maybe you can show your Logstash configuration, so we have more info.

Comment: @Val I just updated my question with logstash info

Comment: Also add the `elasticsearch` output definition, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the following field is necessary for producing the map visualization

```
geoip.location {
  "lat": 38.7163,
  "lon": -78.1704
}
```

The others can be ommited (i.e. `mutate/remove`)